# is this symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

A is the set of all functions $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$

*f* is related to *g* if and only if *f(x)* $\le$ *g(x)* for all x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

I said its reflexive since it is less than OR equal, so f(x)=f(x)

However would it be symmetric and transitive?

I said it would not be symmetric (**counter-example**) because take *x,y* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ if *x=3, y=10* then it would not be symmetric but i'm not too sure...

Also since it is a partial order, is it a total order?

Comment: @julien is it a total order?

Comment: Yes. This is a partial order. As it is also anti-symmetric and transitive. Just because $\mathbb R$  is ordered by $\leq $. And you use that pointwise. It is not total. Can you compare $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=x$?

Comment: It would probably help if you think of it this way: $f\leq g$ if and only if the graph of $f$ is below (large, not strict) that of $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surely not symmetric, as you pointed out in your question. It is actually anti-symmetric, hence your relation (being also reflexive and transitive) turns out to be a (partial) order, not an equivalence.

Comment: one question @Federica Maggioni is this a total order since every a,b is related?

Comment: Can you compare the functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$ this way? What happens for $x = 1$ and $x = -1$?

Comment: @Ghozt As Johannes Kloos noticed, it is not a total order, i.e. there are couples of functions $f,g$ such that you cannot estabilish whether $f$ is less than $g$ or viceversa, e.g. take $f$ and $g$ in Johannes Kloos comment. This is a difference respect to what happens in $\mathbb{R}$,where the order is total